# import an undirected graph in R from text file

Tags: python, r, graph, network-programming, igraph

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iLAj.png) I have trouble reading an undirected graph in R, I've tried to import it to R from a text file "graph.txt" which contains a large number of edges (about 1000) but the problem:

R is not reading the whole graph from the text file and it is omitting a large number of the edges
I followed the steps I have found in tutorials for R and the related previous questions in this website but I couldn't modify it.

The graph.txt looks like:

```
383 886 
777 915 
793 335 
386 492 
649 421 
362 27 
690 59 
763 926 
540 426 
172 736 
211 368 
567 429 
782 530
```

and the functions I used:

```
library("igraph")
dd<-scan("graph.txt")
gg<-read_graph("graph.txt",directed=FALSE)
gg
```

the result looks like:

```
... 763-- 785 326-- 984 946-- 946 326--1103 326-- 592 698--1636 326--1807
+ ... omitted several edges
```

Any help please to let R import the whole number of edges from the txt file

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am trying to import data as a graph only (not a table or matrix) to calculate the diameter for the graph using the function:

```
diameter(graph, directed = FALSE, weights = NULL)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your input txt file please.

Comment: @user20650 thanks for reply.

You can see in the edit how the txt file looks like

Comment: thanks, and do the values represent node labels and the columns from (col one) and to (col two) [ie from -- to] . Also, why do you not want to read it in first, as in R it would be straight forward to read in as a data.frame (`?read.table`) and then form the graph (`?graph_from_data_frame`)

Comment: as you can see in the txt file each edge consist of two nodes

 I didn't understand the second part of your question  @user20650

Comment: @user20650 The text file represent the graph edges I generated previously. Now I want to compute the diameter for the generated graph using "igraph" package so I need to import the text file as a graph to be able to apply:

    diameter(graph, directed = FALSE, weights = NULL)

Comment: @Noah16 With the above example dataset, the problem is not reproducible. Have you tried copying the input file and dropping parts of the file (e.g. first half, last half, etc.) to see at what point the problem occurs? And have you checked to see if there is anything special about the entries in the file corresponding to the missing edges? Can you post the full input file somewhere?

Comment: Noah, please see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132404/noah-igr for an example of reading in as a dataframe and converting to igraph object.

Comment: Actually are you sure it is not getting read in properly, rather than just how it is displayed on the screen? Have a look at this example: `g = igraph::erdos.renyi.game(100, 0.5) ; g` . If you do `E(g)` (or `length(E(g))`) you will see how many edges there are.

Comment: @Keith Hughitt I tried the previous solution but the problem is R can not read more than 64 edge (arranged in 64 rows) and it omits the rest of edges

Comment: @user20650 Yes thats true in your example but when I tried it for my graph you can see the output in the image I've added

Comment: Noah, the image is not clear. What does `length(E(g))` give please?

Comment: Also to double check it is not the print method, can you try looking at the edges after running the following commands please: `options(max.print = length(E(g))) ; print(E(g), TRUE)`

Comment: I think user20650's guess above is correct in that the graph is actually loading just fine, but your only seeing a truncated list of all of the edges when you print `g` to the screen. Check to see if `length(E(g))` and (on the unix command-line) `wc -l graph.txt` are the same; if so then everything has loaded fine.

Comment: @KeithHughitt ; I think we need the op to provide more details!. At least just try loading the file as a data.frame to check its dimensions / check missing etc etc. The image having 9998 vertices with 150 edges would suggest we are missing some details [ if the op expects 1000 edges, as the data is in edge list format (from ->to) then would expect 1000 row dataset:- not sure how you wpould fit 9998 vertcies in 1000x2 dimension edgelist]

Comment: @user20650 Yes it worked and the length is 1000...Many THANKS for help

Comment: @Keith Hughitt Yes thats true, ( user20650) guess is correct in that the graph is actually loading just fine, but I only seeing a truncated list of all of the edges...a bunch of help for you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is import the file first, then convert it to a graph to be safe. So

```
library(igraph)
f <- read.table(file = "graph.txt")
edges <- c()
for (e in 1:dim(f)[1]){
  edges <- append(edges, c(f[e, 1], f[e, 2]))
}
g <- graph(edges, directed = FALSE)
g
#IGRAPH U--- 926 13 -- 
#+ edges:
#[1] 383--886 777--915 335--793 386--492 421--649  27--362  59--690 763--926 426--540 172--736
#[11] 211--368 429--567 530--782
```